# Unresolved class .MainActivity (and all my other classes)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting the error unresolved class in my `AndroidManifest.xml` (and my xml classes under `tools:context="...">`

However there were 0 errors in my gradle rebuild so I'm not sure where the problem is.

There are no red lines in my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.krousorati.truthordare"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha11"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

And my Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }

}
```

And here is my Android manifest file:

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="preloaded_fonts"
                android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: `kotlin_version` ?? Clean-Rebuild-Sync project

Comment: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya added in edit. I manually changed it from `1.2.something` to `1.3.0` by just typing it - not sure if that actually upgraded the version

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file ? i think you have removed the MainActivity.class form there

Comment: @Zorgan You have to add the specific version for the `navigation-ui` and `navigation-fragment` value and also for the kotlin classpath. I mean just change the `$version` from the end of each `implementation` and `classpath` to a version number.

Comment: @Gourav i just changed them to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"` , `implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha11"` and `implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha11"` and I'm still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Then please add the manifest file.

Comment: Added in edit @Gourav

Answer (score 0):

`android:name=".MainActivity"` is a relative class name; expecting `MainActivity.kt` at the root directory of the package; most likely it is located in a sub-directory and therefore cannot be found. either try fixing the relative class name - or simply use a fully qualified class name. unless knowing how the directory structre looks alike it's difficult to tell, but it might be something along the lines of `.activity.MainActivity` or `com.krousorati.truthordare.activity.MainActivity`.

just see what the `package` statement in `MainActivity.kt` says.

Comment: The classes arn't in any folders, they're directly under `java > com.krousorati.truthordare` - I've tried both of your names and it's still not working. Using `.MainActivity` was fine before so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Zorgan `1.3.2` just got released; try updating; try to remove all temporary files. also make sure the `Manifest.xml` starts with `<manifest package="com.krousorati.truthordare" ...`

Comment: Restarted Android studio and it seems to be working now. Thanks.

Comment: This happens very frequently in Kotlin when any layout, class, id, color or any thing stops working and shows unresolved reference. I'm so fed up of this because the solution is to invalidate cache and restart. Any idea why it happens so much in kotlin project and not in java project?